# Catch-all email with specific exceptions on a domain

Tags: linux, email, email-bounces

I want to set up catch-all email on a domain, but also retain the ability to except certain email accounts, such that, if an email is sent to an excepted account, it is bounced back with an "account does not exist" error. What are my options for making this happen? Remotely hosted or self-hosted solutions are fine. Linux-based solutions are preferred in case of self-hosting.

Comment: Any common mailserver on unix can do this.

Answer (score 2):

`sendmail` with the following `virtusertable` entries will do this:

```
fred@example.com                fred
bounce@example.com              error:nouser 550 User unknown   
@example.com                    user294732
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with postfix. Should it?

Comment: @Zulan I'm afraid I have no idea, as I don't use postfix.  I suspect not, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could accomplish this using Postfix's [PCRE tables](http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html). Configure it with `postconf`:

```
postconf -e "virtual_alias_maps=pcre:/etc/postfix/virtusertable"
```

And an e.g. `/etc/postfix/virtusertable` would look like this:

```
/^alex@example\.com$/                alex
/^barry@example\.com$/               barry
/(?<!^corey|dave)@example\.com$/     catch-all
```

Using this, `alex` and `barry` aliases will get delivered, `corey` and `dave` will get rejected and everything else will get routed to catch-all.

Comment: This needs the package `postfix-pcre` on ubuntu. Otherwise there will be errors!

Comment: There is an extensive discussion about this here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/postfix-how-to-reject-incoming-mail-as-in-sendmail's-error-nouser-671883/ - if/endif can be an alternative to the scracy `?<!` regex.